# Is there a need to prepend setTimeout and setInterval with window object?

Tags: javascript, window, settimeout, setinterval

In the Mozilla documentation, there are some examples written with `window.` in front of the timer functions and some without:

```
function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 2000);
}...

setTimeout(myArray.myMethod, 1000);...

window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay...
```

I have been writing my code without `window.` in front without any problem so far. I want to find out if there is any situation when it would be necessary.

Comment: No, as `window` is the global namespace.

Comment: Oh I see you already deleted your other question, either way there's one more way to assign and execute a function inline but it's rather ugly as well: `(o.func = function(){}).call(o);` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhQ2W/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ..

1. There is no other identifier in scope with the given name (`x` or `window`), and;
2. There is no `with` binding that resolves the given name (`x` or `window`), and;
3. The given name (`x`) is a property in the *global scope* (`window`)

.. then `window.x` and `x` are equivalent.

For *standards-mandated* global properties/functions (which must exist in the global scope of a sane web-browser environment), I do not include `window`. I also take care not to shadow such names.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow However, do realize that `window.y` and `y` act a good bit differently when there is *no* such binding: an unbound identifier `y` can throw a ReferenceError, while a non-existent property evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: As in the latter will trigger an error? Yes, I get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No you do not have to add it, the 'window' part is implicit as the root object is `window`. However, people continue to add it as it denotes a built-in, rather than a user defined function.