# What the difference between window.setTimeout() and setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I would like to know what the difference is between

```
window.setTimeout(myFancyFunciton, 1000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(myFancyFunciton, 1000);
```

Both seem to do the exact same thing. When should you use one or the other?

Comment: The former would work only in browser, the latter - anywhere.

Comment: When in a browser, there is no difference since the window object exists.

In other environments it might not exist.

Comment: And where else can work except the browser?

Comment: @user3073240 node.js environment

Comment: @Joe Minichino I don't understand.. :'(

Comment: @user3073240 node.js is a runtime environment for server-side javascript. You can write server-side code (like PHP, Java, Python etc.) in javascript. Look [here](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: @Joe Minichino ah, that's it! thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 46):

JavaScript runs in an environment that is defined by a *global object*. Methods of the global object can be called without explicitly referring to the object (i.e. without the `obj.function()` notation).

When you run JavaScript inside the browser, the global object is provided by the Document Object Model (DOM). The global object of the DOM has a method `setTimeout()`. That's why you can call `setTimeout()`.

The DOM specifies that the global object has a property named `window`, which is a reference back to the global object. That's why you can call `window.setTimeout()` and (by transitivity) `window.window.setTimeout()`, `window.window.window.setTimeout()`, and (you guessed it) `window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.setTimeout()`. It's all the same method of the same object.

Comment: Are Node.js and window `setTimeout` implementations the same except for only the return value type or are there any other differences?

Answer (score 16):

Assuming we're talking about browser-based JavaScript: No difference. `setTimeout()` simply omits the `window.`, which is **implied**. The effect they have is exactly the same.

It's a choice of coding style and preference.

For JavaScript that does not run in a browser, the `window` object is not defined, so `window.setTimeout()` will fail. `setTimeout()` however, will work.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is not part of the ECMAScript specification, so it depends on the spcific global object whether it will work or not.

Answer (score 3):

From  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

> The window object represents the window itself.

So, all variables and functions that you call are enclosed inside the object window. However you can omit the object reference every time you call a function or a variable.

Why this?
Think about a page with 2 or more frames. Every frame has own `window`. You can access to a variable inside a frame from another frame simply accessing to the `window` object of the target.
This is valid for every variable or function declared as global... and it's valid too for native functions, like `setTimeout`.

So why sometimes we need to write explicity `window.setTimeout`?

Simply, if you are inside a scope and you use the same name of a native function, you can choose which function to use.

for example:

```
function myF() {
  function setTimeout(callback,seconds) {
    // call the native setTimeout function
    return window.setTimeout(callback,seconds*1000); 
  }
  // call your own setTimeout function (with seconds instead of milliseconds)
  setTimeout(function() {console.log("hi"); },3);

}
myF();
```

Please note that the object `window` exists only in browser environment. The global object of `Node.js` is `global` where `window` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same. Window is implicit if you don't specify it. Check out possible duplicate:

[Is there a need to prepend setTimeout and setInterval with window object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111612/is-there-a-need-to-prepend-settimeout-and-setinterval-with-window-object)

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue related to this topic. I tried to make some functionality of my SPA to be a part of server side rendering proccess. I used `setTimeout` to provide some deferred action on the UI. When it works on server side (NodeJS) it turns into deferred action on the server side with no relation to the client side. It's because of Browser `setTimeout` (say `window.setTimeout`) is not the same as NodeJS `setTimeout`. Apart from different runtime environments, which prohibits using a single `setTimeout` both for client side and server side rendering, the implementations of [Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) `setTimeout` are different, they have different return value... Now I'm looking for some workaround.